# Is boolean or nil comparison faster?

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, filter, comparison

I am writing a code in Swift where I have a class as follows:

```
class Note
{
    var isDeleted:Bool = false
    var deletedDateTime:Date!
}
```

Suppose there is a data source that is filled with Notes and I want to make a filter based on comparison, then I can either compare by `isDeleted` or I can compare by `deletedDateTime`. Which one would be faster from the following two statements:

```
var dataSource:[Note] = [Note]()
// fill the datasource with objects

dataSource.filter({$0.isDeleted == false})       // 1
dataSource.filter({$0.deletedDateTime == nil}) //2
```

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: I believe checking for either would not make a huge time difference

Comment: I doubt that there is a significant difference, but what did *you* measure?

Comment: At the lowest level, both load a value and check to see if it's zero. If there's a difference in the execution time, it's going to be on the order of nanoseconds. Rather than worrying about micro-optimizations here, concentrate instead on making the code as clear as possible. The `boolean` value is more explicit: testing for `isDeleted` clearly states what you're doing. Checking for a non-existent `deletedDateTime` is indirect; it's not as clear. A good compromise would be to eliminate the `boolean` value and have an `isDeleted` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be much of a time difference, if you are talking about the execution time. But your class seem to be a bit obvious since you could remove the unnecessary boolean variable because as you have asked the both mean the same.

Comment: "There won't be much of a time difference." Actually, there won't be any time difference. The time require for a bit comparison versus the time required for a 64 bit word comparison is irrelevant. Both require the same number of cycles.